# ASP Classic - Find in long string and remove

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I need to find some text in a very long string, and remove the beginning and the ending.

Example:    [proimg:thisisaimage.jpg]this is me[/proimg]

OK, now. what I need, is only the image itself.  thisisaimage.jpg

Not the rest of the stuff.

I can find and replace, of which I tested, and it will find and replace.

```
<%txt = ReplaceChar("[proimg:")
response.Write replace(txt, "proimg","MyImg")%>
```

but how to get just the image?

Any idea's?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from another site. here is a working code, which I have tested and ran, against a page with over 10,000 characters, and this works beautifully!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
String search example from @delradie 12/1/2016
<br />
<br />
<%
Dim StartPosition
 Dim EndPosition
 Dim Output
 Dim Input

 Input = "[proimg:thisisaimage.jpg]this is me[/proimg]"

 StartPosition = InStr(Input, "[proimg:")

 If (StartPosition >= 0) Then
   StartPosition = StartPosition + 8
   EndPosition = InStr(StartPosition , Input, "]")

            if(EndPosition > StartPosition) Then
                  Response.Write(Mid(Input, StartPosition , (EndPosition - StartPosition)))
            Else
                  Response.Write("End Not Found")
            End If
   Else   
   Response.Write("Start Not Found")
 End If
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `[img:` is constant, read 6 character from the left of it until the next `|`

```
pos = instr(str, "[img:")
str = mid(str, pos + 5, instr(pos, str, "|") - (pos + 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.
It is a very long string, so there could be 50 or 1,000 characters, with this object being in the middle of it... So, unfortunately, the code your provided will not work in this case...

Comment: Edited to find `[img:` anywhere

Comment: If you can make it so that is find the [img: tag, then it might work..?

Comment: I am getting this error.  Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'

Comment: Would happen if there was another | before img, fixed above.

Comment: In this example page that I am doing, there is nothing in it, the code is a little different then what i originally posted. it is like this..... [proimg=01122016112658159.jpg]Image Name Here[/proimg]

Comment: I just caught onto what I posted above, and dang. I messed up on the original.... Please look at my last comment (OR) look at the original post, for the changes to the code, and what to look for...  So very sorry.

Comment: I was able to get the answer from another site. Please have a look at my Answer below. Thank you for your time and assistance in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know vbscript but according to the docs this should work

```
split1 = Split(str,'|',1) 
split2 = Split(split1(0),':')
txt = split2(1)
```

Comment: I made a mistake on me code, so the | does not exist. it is a ]
Please look at my original post at the code again.

Comment: Is the ] just after the image the first one which appears in the string ? if so you just replace split1 = Split(str,']',1)

Comment: Thank lyz, but I was able to get a code that did the job from another source. Please look at my Answer that I posted. Take care and thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two set parameters that fall before and after the image name and are constant this may work for you. 
I use this type of script to pull cookie data from session cookies (httponly)

Using your example:  [proimg:thisisaimage.jpg]this is me[/proimg]

```
Dim str, j, strTemp
str = "[proimg:thisisaimage.jpg]this is me[/proimg]"
If InStr(str,"proimg:") Then
   j = InStrRev(str,"proimg:")
     If j > 0 Then
       strTemp = Mid(str,j+7)
     End If
   j = InStr(strTemp,".jpg") 
     If j > 0 Then
        strTemp = Left(strTemp,j-0)
     End If
str = strTemp
End If
```

I've use this on querystrings that are very long as long as you have a fixed start point and ending point you can extract instead of replace.